# My solving is correct? (Fourier - Bessel function)

Tags: proof-verification

My professor gives us the problem: Prove that
$$
 J_0(2\pi f_D\tau) \quad \underset{\mathcal{F}^{-1}}{\stackrel{\mathcal{F}}{\rightleftharpoons}} \quad \frac{1}{4\pi f_D\sqrt{1-(f/f_D)^2}},
$$
where
$$
J_0(t) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi e^{jt\cos\theta} {~d\theta}.
$$

---

My solving is:

1. Let us first arrange $J_0(t)$ into the form of $\displaystyle\int^\infty_{-\infty} f(\omega) e^{j\omega t} d\omega$.
   \begin{align}
    J_0(t)
    &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{jt\cos\theta} {~d\theta} \label{1} \\
    &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2} e^{jt\sin\phi} {~d\phi} \label{2} \\
    &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2} \left[ \cos{\left(t\sin\phi\right)} + j\sin{\left(t\sin\phi\right)} \right] {~d\phi} \label{3} \\
    &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2} \cos{\left(t\sin\phi\right)} {~d\phi} \label{4} \\
    &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\cos{\left(t\omega\right)}}{\sqrt{1-\omega^2}} {~d\omega} \label{5} \\
    &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1} \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\omega^2}} \right] e^{j\omega t} {~d\omega} \label{6} \\
    &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[ \Pi(\omega) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\omega^2}} \right] e^{j\omega t} {~d\omega}  \label{7}
   \end{align}
   (1): from the zero-th order Bessel function of the 1st kind, (2): by the integration by substitution $\left(\cos\theta \to \sin\phi\right)$, (3): by Euler's formula, (4): by the fact that the imaginary part is odd, (5): by the integration by substitution $\left(\sin\phi \to \omega\right)$, (6): by the odd property of the sine function, and (7): by introducing the modified rect function $\Pi(x)$ whose value is $1$ for $x\in(-1,1)$ and $0$ for $x\in(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)$.
2. Substituting $t \to 2\pi f_D \tau$ in the eq. (\ref{7}), we have
   \begin{align}
    J_0(2{\pi}f_D{\tau})
    &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[ \Pi(\omega) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\omega^2}} \right] e^{j\omega2{\pi}f_D{\tau}} {~d\omega} \label{8} \\
    &= \frac{1}{{\pi}{f_D}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[ \Pi\left(\frac{f}{f_D}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(f/f_D)^2}} \right] e^{j2{\pi}f{\tau}} {~df} \label{9} \\
    &= \frac{1}{{\pi}{f_D}} ~\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left\{ \Pi\left(\frac{f}{f_D}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(f/f_D)^2}} \right\} \label{10}
   \end{align}
   (8): from the previous result, (9): by the integration by substitution $\left(\omega f_D \to f\right)$, and (10): by the definition of the inverse Fourier transform.
3. Since $J_0$ and its Fourier transform are absolutely integrable in the Lebesgue sense and it is continuous on the domain $(-f_D, f_D)$,
   \begin{align}
    \mathcal{F}\left\{ J_0(2{\pi}f_D{\tau}) \right\}
    &= \frac{1}{{\pi}{f_D}}\left\{ \Pi\left(\frac{f}{f_D}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(f/f_D)^2}} \right\} \label{11} \\
    &=\left\{
    \begin{array}{cl}
     \displaystyle\frac{1}{{\pi}f_D\sqrt{1-(f/f_D)^2}} & \text{if }\left\vert f \right\vert < f_D\\
     0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{array}\right. \label{12} \\
    &= \mathbf{1}_{|f|<f_D} \cdot \frac{1}{{\pi}f_D\sqrt{1-(f/f_D)^2}} \label{13}
   \end{align}
   (11): by the Fourier inversion theorem, (12): by the definition of the function $\Pi$, and (13): by introducing the indicator function.

---

I really don't think where $4$ in the denominator is come from. Is my solving correct and the professor just made a mistake?

Comment: There is a problem in the first derivation where you substitute $\cos(t\omega)\rightarrow e^{j\omega t}$. You should get a factor 2 here and another one from the two exponentials. Your professor is right.

Comment: @Jon Could you tell me more a detail? Is the following wrong? $\int_{-1}^1 \cos(tw) dw = \int_{-1}^1 \cos(tw) + j\sin(tw) dw = \int_{-1}^{1} e^{jwt} dw$

Comment: I explained this in the answer.